# Оформление внутренней речи

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, прямая-речь, несобственно-прямая-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли кавычки в следующем предложении?

*Но установка "Я должна работать, как все" всё ещё сидела в голове.*

И оправданно ли написание местоимения с прописной буквы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки, конечно, нужны – без них предложение будет графически неряшливым.
*"Я должна работать, как все"* может быть прямой речью, невысказанной мыслью (внутренней речью), а также своеобразным названием одной из установок, поэтому прописная буква совершенно оправданна.

> **2.** Независимо от места, занимаемого по отношению к словам автора, кавычками выделяется внутренняя речь — невысказанные мысли. [[**Розенталь, § 47**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154)]

> **Примечание.** Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится:
> <...>
> *Он вспомнил пословицу **«За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь»** и отказался от первоначального плана.* [[**Розенталь, § 51**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154)]

> г) если прямая речь непосредственно включается в авторское предложение в качестве его члена, то она заключается в кавычки, знаки же препинания ставятся по условиям авторского предложения: *Сказав Гричмару фразу **«Легкой жизни не бывает, есть лишь легкая смерть»**, Крымов поймал на себе беспокойный, предупреждающий взгляд Стишова* (Бонд.). [[**ПАС, § 136**](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=442#)]

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!